# Is there in Python to check if the tools collapsible menu is open/closed?

Tags: python, modifiers, interface, add-on

I'm trying to see if there is a way for me to get a boolean value for the **tools** menu being opened or closed. I know you can see a few toggle options using something like console.toggle() but I wasn't able to find anything about the tools menu in the Blender Documentation or other similar questions on this platform. Thanks!

[image: The tools menu open]
Tools Menu Open

[image: The tools menu closed]
Tools Menu Closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fiddled a bit in the python console and found the `show_region_ui` property of the 3D Viewport space indicating this:

```
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        for space in area.spaces:
            if space.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                # True: n-panel is open
                # False: n-panel is closed
                n_panel_is_open = space.show_region_ui

                # You can even set it
                if not n_panel_is_open:
                    space.show_region_ui = True

                break
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is show_region_ui in the docs? Every time I search for it I don't get results... this is such a useful method to know!

Comment: Well, technically [there is an entry](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.show_region_ui) in the docs, but it is explaining nothing, so not of much use.